# Why is image onload not working

Tags: javascript

I realize this is a common question asked by novice javascript programmers which I am. Console.log(img) and console.log("before onload") execute correctly but I never see an Image Loaded message.

```
AssetManager.loadImages = function(urls) {
   var images = [];
   var urlCount = urls.length;
   for (var i=0; i<urlCount; i++) {
      var img = new Image();
      images.push(img);
   }
   var urlsLoaded = 0;
   for (var i=0; i<urlCount; i++) {
      (function(img) {
         console.log(img);
         console.log("before onload");
         img.onload = function(e) {
            console.log("Image Loaded!");
            urlsLoaded++;
            if (urlsLoaded >= urlCount) {
               AssetManager.callback(images);
            }
         }
      })(images[i]);            
      images[i].src = urls[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: This may be an obvious question, but are you sure the images exist? Try adding `img.onerror = function() {console.log("Image failed!");};`

Comment: which browser(s) is this happening in?

Comment: My guess is that it's because the image is already loaded and is being fetched from the browser cache. I think I've seen this before.

Comment: The `load` event of an image element won't occur if it's been cached by the browser. If you want to make sure it always grabs an image, you can add something like `"?_=" + (new Date()).getTime()` to the URL

Comment: images dont trigger an onload event

Comment: Why are you looping multiple times? That is a waste of time. Do everything in one step.

Comment: @ogc-nick Yeah they do. But only if they aren't cached

Comment: @Ian Thanks! So unfortunately though I guess it is not a reliable trigger unless you prevent caching. I didn't know that it was triggered on the initial load.

Answer (score 11):

`onload` doesn't fire if the image is being loaded from cache. You can use the `complete` property to check for this case.

```
if(img.complete){
   // do the work
} else {
   img.onload = () => {
       // do the work
   }
}
```

You can use a function to keep the code DRY.

Comment: Also check this article https://scottiestech.info/2022/11/08/javascript-how-to-detect-when-an-image-is-loaded/

TL;DR 
img.complete can be true even if the image url is “broken". So if you want to ensure that your img is loaded correctly, you also need check that ".naturalHeight attribute is greater than 0"

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who made the same mistake as me - make sure onload is all lowercase and not camel case: onLoad.

This good:

```
img.onload = function () { };
```

This bad:

```
img.onLoad = function () { };
```

Comment: Keep in mind it's definitely camelcase as a prop in HTML: <img onLoad=>.

Comment: Still does not fire with onload, must be something else going on

Answer (score 6):

Try `var img = document.createElement("img");`

or

```
AssetManager.loadImages = function(urls) {
    var images = new Array();
    var urlCount = urls.length;
    var urlsLoaded = 0;
    var leImg;
    for (var i=0; i<urlCount; i++) {
        leImg = document.createElement("img");
        leImg.onload = function(e){
            urlsLoaded++;
            if (urlsLoaded >= urlCount) {
               // AssetManager.callback(images); --> this is balls, still
            }
        }
        leImg.src = urls[i];
        _images.push(leImg);
    }

}
```

(not tested, and drunk)

Answer (score 1):

"img.onload" function when call in nested function not work exact

you need call "img.onload" function explicit in "$().ready (function(){  }" or  "window.onload = function() { }"

e.g

```
$().ready (function(){ 

 var img = new Image();
 img.src = 'image.png';
 img.onload = function()
 {
  console.log("loaded");
 }
}
```

Comment: always set src after setting onload or you will get race conditions with cached images

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the exact problem is with your code, but here's some code I wrote awhile back to handle the same problem (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LJRSL/) There's some extra stuff in there that's probably not necessary :)

```
$.preloadImg = function (url, callback, to_len) { //to_length = image fetch timeout in ms
    var img = new Image(),
        $img = $(img),
        st = new Date().getTime(),
        to;

    if (callback && $.isFunction(callback)) {

        to = window.setTimeout(function () {
            callback.call(this, url, true);
        }, to_len || 5000);

    }


    $img
        .on('load', function () {
            to = window.clearTimeout(to);

            if ($.isFunction(callback))
                callback.call(this, url, false);
        })
        .attr('src', url)
        ;
    /*this is probably unnecessary*/
    if (img.complete) {
        $img.off('load');
        if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
            to = window.clearTimeout(to);

            callback.call(this, url);
        }
    }
};

$.preloadImg('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png', function(img) { $('#test').attr('src', img); alert('done'); });
```

and for good measure loading multiple:

```
$.preloadImgs = function (urls, callback, to_len) {
    var i = 0, c = 0;
    for (; i < urls.length; i++) {
        c++;
        $.preloadImg(urls[i], function (url, timedout) {
            if (--c === 0 && i >= urls.length - 1)
                callback.call(this, urls);
        }, to_len);
    }
};
```

You might try binding your event via `addEventListener` instead of `onload =`

Comment: Where is jQuery in the original question?

Comment: No where. Glad you took the time to contribute ;)

Comment: This may be an obvious question, but are you sure the images exist? Try adding img.onerror = function() {console.log("Image failed!");};

Comment: I hate to admit it but this was the winner in all the responses. I must have messed up the path.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. I noticed that my image `.onload` was not being called if the page is reloaded normally, if I reloaded the page using f12 + right click reload button and chose `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`, the `.onload` was called.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30578892)

Comment: Tried pressing f12+right click and my system went to sleep ‍♂️